# Handling default values in window aggregations

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have an aggregation that looks at a sliding 30-day window (1 day period) of customer purchases, keyed by customer id, with the value being the purchase amount. I sum up the values by key, thus getting the aggregate purchase amount for each customer during the last 30 days. I store this number in a customer record in an external database.

My question is this: if a customer hasn't purchased anything in the last 30 days, how do I automatically reset the customer record to a default value, in this case zero? I'd prefer to keep all my logic in Dataflow and avoid doing too much work, since this will need to scale quite a bit. I'm basically looking for a way to automatically get a key-value for each key that was *not* in the current window but *was* in the last, and the value being a potentially configurable default.

Comment: Can you clarify: once you see a customer at least once, do you expect to see their data to keep appearing in every window forever if they never purchase anything again?

Comment: No: if they only ever purchase one product, I would expect to see a `(customerId, amount)` element once, as well as a single `(customerId, 0)` element when the purchase event drops out of the window.

Comment: So with 30-day (1 day period) windows, the (customerId, amount) element will be associated with thirty 30-day-long windows, sliding around the day of the purchase. In which window or windows do you want the (customerId, 0) element to appear? Perhaps it'll be helpful if you explain why you want this zero element - does it help some downstream processing? There might be an easier way to accomplish your ultimate goal.

Comment: I only want the element *after* a window in which there's an actual value for a given key. Basically, I'm upserting a customer profile in an external database with a field "purchases-last-month". If I don't make sure there's a default value being emitted somehow, that field would never reset to zero after a purchase.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It seems like you're assuming that windows will be processed in time order. This is not the case - Beam programming model makes no such guarantee. Different windows of the same key may be processed out-of-order or even in parallel. Let me think a bit more about how to address this.

Comment: Would the answer I wrote farther down the page work, you think?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to answer my own question, but hoping for feedback as to whether this solution would scale:

I've thought about having a step *after* the initial window-and-sum. This transform would receive `(customerId, purchaseSum)` elements once a day, as the result of the 30-day window sum is made available. Since these elements are timestamped (with the timestamp of the most recent input element, I believe) I can re-window them. If I create a two-day window with a one-day period, I would then be able to group by key and process `(customerId, [purchaseSumA, purchaseSumB])` for customers that had a purchase *both* in the last 30 days *and* in the last 31 days. In this case, I emit `purchaseSumB`. However, if there's only in element in the list, and the timestamp indicates that the purchase was made 31 days ago, I can assume that there were no purchases from the customer since, and I need to emit `(customerId, 0)`. Does that make sense?

Comment: This sounds like it'll likely work in practice, if you use a streaming pipeline, and if you don't have very late or out-of-order data. However, again, this is making the assumption about the order in which the different (customerId, [purchaseSumA, purchaseSumB]) windowed elements will be processed even within a single customerId - they may be processed in a different order, and they may be processed in parallel. This *most likely* will not happen if your data arrives more or less in order, but once this assumption is violated, all bets are off.

Comment: Hmm. I remember reading through the Dataflow source code (can't remember where) and seeing a transform that employed a trick to get _all_ values with a key in the window – it used an empty main input pcollection but the _real_ pcollection as a side input. Would that be feasible if the number of values for a key is low (hundreds, at most thousands)?

Comment: "all values with a key in the window" is, unfortunately, also not a well-defined concept in a pipeline that can have late data. In practice, if you employ that solution, you'll get all values from the last trigger firing - see https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-inputs-and-windowing

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option to slightly amend the database schema? I suppose now you have something like

```
(customer_id int, purchases_last_month int)`
```

Instead how about

```
`(customer_id int, last_purchase datetime, purchases_last_month int)`
```

where this time `last_purchase` is the time of the last purchase made by this customer, and `purchases_last_month` refers to purchases made in the month before the last one? Then in your `DoFn` that writes to the database, you'd be making a conditional update (merge/upsert) that updates both `last_purchase` and `purchases_last_month` with the values from the current window, but only if `last_purchase` is increasing. This way you can deal with windows being processed out-of-order or in parallel, at the cost of slight increase in complexity in client queries (which you can address by adding a view on top of the table).

Comment: I'm not sure that's an option – I'm going to be sending these records out of the system, and any other application can subscribe to them over PubSub...